# ogr2ogr convert WFS data, when WFS has password and username

Tags: qgis, wfs, ogr2ogr

I am trying to use ogr2ogr on a WFS with username and password.

I tried to follow this answer here
[Import data from password protected WFS using OGR2OGR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263803/import-data-from-password-protected-wfs-using-ogr2ogr)

Does anyone have some examples of doing this?

https://services.datafordeler.dk/GeoDanmarkVektor/GeoDanmark60_NOHIST_GML3/1.0.0/WFS?username=XXXX&password=XXXX

Comment: Make a test by editing the XML file example in the answer to include your URL, username, and password. Then test the connection `ogrinfo my_wfs_config.xml` and tell how it goes.

Comment: I did a test with: 
<OGRWFSDataSource> <URL>https://services.datafordeler.dk/GeoDanmarkVektor/GeoDanmark60_NOHIST_GML3/1.0.0/WFS?</URL>
    <UserPwd>USERNAME:PASSWORD</UserPwd>
    <HttpAuth>BASIC</HttpAuth>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
</OGRWFSDataSource>

and got "Unable to open datasource `wfs.xml' with the following drivers.

I am able to run a ogrinfo with: ogrinfo WFS:"https://services.datafordeler.dk/GeoDanmarkVektor/GeoDanmark60_NOHIST_GML3/1.0.0/WFS?username=USER&password=PASSWORD&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities"

Comment: what if you use "ANY" instead of "BASIC"

Answer (score 1):

I tried this XML file "wfstest.xml"

```
<OGRWFSDataSource>
<URL>https://services.datafordeler.dk/GeoDanmarkVektor/GeoDanmark60_NOHIST_GML3/1.0.0/WFS?</URL>
<UserPwd>USERNAME:PASSWORD</UserPwd> 
<HttpAuth>BASIC</HttpAuth> 
<Version>1.0.0</Version> 
</OGRWFSDataSource>
```

I tested the XML file with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo wfstest.xml --debug on
...
WFS: https://services.datafordeler.dk/GeoDanmarkVektor/GeoDanmark60_NOHIST_GML3/1.0.0/WFS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
HTTP: Fetch(https://services.datafordeler.dk/GeoDanmarkVektor/GeoDanmark60_NOHIST_GML3/1.0.0/WFS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities)
HTTP: libcurl/7.79.1-DEV OpenSSL/1.1.1l zlib/1.2.11
ERROR 1: Failed to connect to services.datafordeler.dk port 443 after 2222 ms: Connection refused
ERROR 1: Error returned by server : Failed to connect to services.datafordeler.dk port 443 after 2222 ms: Connection refused (7)
```

At least GDAL tries to connect the right address and makes a reasonable WFS request. Please try with your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively it is possible to use the configuration options https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html

> **GDAL_HTTP_AUTH=[BASIC/NTLM/GSSNEGOTIATE/ANY]**
>
> Set value to tell libcurl which authentication method(s) you want it
> to use. See
>
> **GDAL_HTTP_USERPWD=value**
>
> The HTTP user and password to use for the connection. Must be in the
> form of [user name]:[password]. Use GDAL_HTTP_AUTH to decide the
> authentication method.
>
> When using NTLM, you can set the domain by prepending it to the user
> name and separating the domain and name with a forward (/) or backward
> slash (). Like this: "domain/user:password" or "domainuser:password".
> Some HTTP servers (on Windows) support this style even for Basic
> authentication.